# Object reference not instantiated after instantiation (consuming WS of SAP Enterprise Service Workspace)

Tags: c#, .net, service, enterprise

I am trying to consume some of these services in .Net/C#. Some of the Service could be easily consumed but with others I have got a **misleading error**.

This a part of the code:

```
input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName = new AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryMessage_syncAcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName();
input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName.AcademicProgramOfStudyName.languageCode = "DE";
```

I am getting at the second line the error

> Object reference not set to an object instance

but I have created the object in the first line!

The same code works in some other service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you created the object
`input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName`, but you did not create its member `input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName.AcademicProgramOfStudyName`. As it seems, the constructor of class `AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryMessage_syncAcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName` does not populate its member `AcademicProgramOfStudyName`. So when you try to assign a value to a member of `AcademicProgramOfStudyName` and that instance is `NULL`, you get an exception.

Example code:

```
    AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryResponse_InClient client = 
        new AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryResponse_InClient(); 


    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "XX";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "YY";

    AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryMessage_sync input =
        new AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryMessage_sync();


    input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName = new AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryMessage_syncAcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName();

    // this is the member that currently is still NULL and has to be created:
    input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName.AcademicProgramOfStudyName = new <insert whatever class is needed here>

    // now this should work without throwing an exception
   input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName.AcademicProgramOfStudyName.languageCode = "DE";

    AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameResponseMessage_sync output = 
        new AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameResponseMessage_sync(); 

    output = client.AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryResponse_In(input);
```

Comment: thank you for the Answer but i am wondering why i dont get the same error for example in this service:             input.CustomerSimpleSelectionByNameAndAddress = new CustomerSimpleByNameAndAddressQueryMessage_syncCustomerSimpleSelectionByNameAndAddress();
            input.CustomerSimpleSelectionByNameAndAddress.CustomerAddressCityName = "ANYCiTY";

Comment: without having a look at the constructor of these classes i can't say. Where do the classes come from? 3rd party library, automatically created service proxy classes, self-created classes?

Comment: They are automatically generated when i consume the service in C#(Add Service Reference) and i am oriented at the example below
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/905c28e4-38a9-2910-4db5-d39e4fcbf78b?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&12309376286992

Comment: when they are automatically created you will have to create these member instances yourself. I don't think the automatically generated code will do that for you.

Comment: sorry, but this is so plain basic oop i'm not sure what to explain. You just picked the wrong class. You need to create an object of the type AcademicProgramOfStudyName is declared with. That AcademicProgramOfStudyName is a member of some other class doesn't matter at all here. So take a look at the definition of that member, create the appropriate object and be done with it.

Comment: I am sorry if i asked a basic question. I have looked as you said at the definition of the AcademicProgramOfStudyName and found the right class which was MEDIUM_Name with this
input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName.AcademicProgramOfStudyName = new MEDIUM_Name();
i dont have anymore error. Thank you alot.

Answer (score 0):

it is really strange. see this compare:
In this code i get the error

```
        AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryResponse_InClient client = 
            new AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryResponse_InClient(); 


        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "XX";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "YY";

        AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryMessage_sync input =
            new AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryMessage_sync();


        input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName = new AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryMessage_syncAcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName();
        input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName.AcademicProgramOfStudyName.languageCode = "DE";

        AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameResponseMessage_sync output = 
            new AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameResponseMessage_sync(); 

        output = client.AcademicProgramOfStudyByNameQueryResponse_In(input);
```

and in this code i dont!!

```
        CustomerSimpleByNameAndAddressQueryResponse_InClient client =
          new CustomerSimpleByNameAndAddressQueryResponse_InClient();

        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "XX";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "YY";

        CustomerSimpleByNameAndAddressQueryMessage_sync input = new CustomerSimpleByNameAndAddressQueryMessage_sync();

        input.CustomerSimpleSelectionByNameAndAddress = new CustomerSimpleByNameAndAddressQueryMessage_syncCustomerSimpleSelectionByNameAndAddress();
        input.CustomerSimpleSelectionByNameAndAddress.CustomerAddressCityName = "Berlin";

        CustomerSimpleByNameAndAddressResponseMessage_sync output = new CustomerSimpleByNameAndAddressResponseMessage_sync();

        output = client.CustomerSimpleByNameAndAddressQueryResponse_In(input);
```

Comment: yes of course, have a closer look at what you are doing there. Example 1: input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName.AcademicProgramOfStudyName.languageCode is a member of another object, whereas in example 2 input.CustomerSimpleSelectionByNameAndAddress.CustomerAddressCityName is a simple string member of CustomerSimpleSelectionByNameAndAddress. If you create the object input.AcademicProgramOfStudySelectionByName.AcademicProgramOfStudyName before accessing one of its members, the error in example 1 will disappear.